# How to add many elements to an array with useState?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

This is how you add one element to items

```
const [items, setItems] = useState
setItems([...items, newElm ]);
```

But what if I wanted to add/concatenate an array of elements to items. This doesn't work

```
const [items, setItems] = useState
setItems([...items, newArr ]);
```

How would I do this?

Comment: `setItems([...items, ...newArr])`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to spread the new array just as the items array.

Remember that the recommended way to merge the new `items` array with your current state is as follows:

```
setItems(prevState => ([...prevState, ...newArray]))
```

In this way you can ensure that `prevState` will have an updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Spread the elements of the new array into the state

`const [items, setItems] = useState setItems([...items, ...newArr ]);`